# HTML: Make all 3 columns equal height (auto-resizing)

Tags: html, css

The following is a 3 column web layout template, with header and footer divs.

The primary column is intentionally the first listed in the html to ensure that it's content has the best possible placement from an SEO point of view.

The current code has the following two flaws:

1. Each div is only as long as it's content necessitates and therefore it can be seen that they are unequal lengths if a background colour is used.
2. If the page is only short (for example, "Thank you. Your message was sent"), then the footer ends up  half way down the page and I would rather that it appeared at the bottom of the view-port in this instance, with the left and right divs being extended to maintain consistency.

I've also created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snowweb/VyrNA/2/) but the initial code is below for completeness.

HTML:

```
<div class='layout'>
    <div class="header">
        domain.com
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="primary">
                Primary Content (centre column)
            </div>
            <div class="left-col">
                Left hand content
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            Right hand content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <strong>&copy; All rights reserved</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layout {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.header, .footer {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
}

.primary {
    background: #FBA95E;
}

.left-col {
    background-color: #B9B9FF;
}

.right-col {
    background-color: #B9B9FF;
}

.header, .footer, .primary, .left-col, .right-col {
    padding: 10px 2%;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.content {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.primary, .left-col, .right-col {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 78%;
}

.primary {
    float: right;
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}

.left-col {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-col {
    float: right;
    width: 16.5%;
}
```

How can I overcome the two problems mentioned above please?

Comment: Both of those problems have been discussed broadly on the net already … “equal height columns” and “sticky footer” are your search terms.

Comment: I'm unable to find any such discussion which places any importance on putting the main content in the first div above the two side column divs in the code. If someone is able to give me a link to a discussion which does and solves the problem, I will accept that as an answer.

Comment: @CBroe +1 because 'sticky footer' looks like it will be half of my solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use position:absolute; bottom:0; for the footer.

Comment: The problem with this is that when content over-runs the available view-port requiring scrolling, the footer remains stationary, instead of being repositioned below the extended content.

Comment: @Peter No worries, then the sticky footer method is the way to go, google it and it will come straight up, hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like that might solve one of the problems. I'd never heard of it and wouldn't have guessed the search term. +1'd (x2) as I rekon it's done me some favours, but not enough to close the question.